# Comma before a dependent clause and the word 'respectively'

Tags: punctuation

I am trying to write the following sentence:

*The Senate comprises 76 members, with each state and territory having 12 and 2 senators, respectively.*

Should there be a comma before *with* and *respectively*?

Comment: I read your sentence as meaning that you are discussing a federation consisting of a number of States and a different number of Territories where each State returns 12 senators and each Territory returns 2 senators. If there are S States and T Territories you are also saying that 12S + 2T = 76 which suggests that there are 6 States and 2 Territories.

Comment: Yes, it's about Australia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence is correct as you have written it.

"Respectively" is a free modifier, modifying "with each state and territory having 12 and 2 senators" adverbially.

Free modifiers are always offset by commas. e.g. "Unfortunately, the rope broke" / "The rope broke, unfortunately."

See also this Online Writing course on Free modifiers: http://writingwithaesop.blogspot.com/2011/01/commas-and-free-modifiers.html

Answer (score 0):

*respectively* is an adverb and qualifies "having". It might also be  placed next to its verb: "each state having respectively 12 and 3 senators".

Cambridge dictionary examples parallel yours and have no comma. The comma is not needed.

> respectively adverb UK  /rɪˈspek.tɪv.li/ US  /rɪˈspek.tɪv.li/
>
> in a way that relates or belongs to each of the separate people or things you have just mentioned:
> "In the 200 metres, Lizzy and Sarah came first and third respectively (= Lizzy won the race and Sarah was third)."
> "Steven and James are aged 10 and 13 respectively."